# MS Access Event Model - Intercept Record Write

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access form whose underlying table is a MySQL view that uses correlated queries, so I can't write records directly using the form - I get an ODBC error "Insert on linked table ABC failed..."

What I'd like to do is:

- catch the actual write event (in MS Access)
- write the underlying MYSQL table based on values from the MS Access form
- bypass any further write record action initiated by MS Access (i.e. reset
  Me.Dirty)

Is there a single event where MS Access writes the underlying table? I've tried: Before Update (see below), After Update, etc...

If there is a single event (that writes a record), how can I bypass the write, do my own updates and proceed to the next event?

- I think what I'm asking is how to reset Me.Dirty without using DoCmd.Undo.

**Before Update Event**

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

msgbox ("Intercept Event")

Cancel = True

End Sub

This actually does seem to intercept the attempted write,  but...

- Me.Dirty is still true
- DoCmd.Undo would clear Me.Dirty, but would also clear the form controls.
- If I was to add Me.Dirty = False after Cancel = True, then I think Access will try to write the record (when I tried it, I got an error 2115)

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read, it won't get you help any faster, and it's somewhat rude. Thanks.

Comment: it seems unnecessary to do what you saying. Just use unbound forms and write sql based on the derived values of the controls.

Comment: I'll amplify what Doug said. You're trying to "break" Access's inbuilt methods and workings, when an unbound form would do exactly what you wanted.

Comment: If the view can't be updated, then break each table out to a sub form. You in general with any system can't use a single SQL source that updates multiple tables. Either get a updateable view working, or break out the related tables into sub forms (each form attached to the correct linked table). You then drop the multiple sub forms onto one form.